# Reading/Writing a usb flash drive

Tags: microcontroller, usb, microprocessor, 8085

I wish to expose a usb flash drive and read it as raw binary data, particularly read each byte & simultaneously writing it to another flash drive.

Given that I am working with an 8085 microprocessor, & I am in a position to program it & read data from secondary memory device, how can I start working with the usb.

I have tried to understand USB from this:

http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml

But I still have no idea how I would be writing my program to host flash drives.

Comment: Your project would be drastically similar if you could use SD cards (or SPI flashes) in place of USB sticks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FTDI's [Vinculum](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/VNC1L.htm) embedded USB host may be of interest to you.

It handles most of the protocol details, and gives you SPI/FIFO access to the USB Device.

Comment: +1 embedded host - you can't talk to the flash drives without it.  This is the hard part...most of the literature that's available focuses on embedded devices or full-sized PC host controllers.

Comment: @ajs410 - well, you *could* talk to a flash drive without it, but you'd have to write a soft-usb-host, and that's an exercise for the masochistic only. USB is rather complex under-the-hood.

Answer (score 3):

I would look for a reference design for both the hardware and software to get you going.  The website you have linked to is good night time reading and background, but actually implementing have a search for some code examples.

Check this site from Atmel, it has some software examples for the various 8051 subsystems and should help you get going for USB.

http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools.asp?family_id=604#1535

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/6   This company has some products to allow 
interaction between selected  usb devices and mcu's and appears fairly adaptable.
Seems like it would be a great addon allowing easy expansion of memory perhaps.